# Angular2 - [disabled] button issue with chrome autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, angular

For a simple login form, the login button is set to be disabled like following:
    `[disabled]="!password || !loginName"`
And Chrome `autocomplete` will fill in those value. But after the page is loaded with `loginName` and `password` auto filled in, the button still disabled at the first load. I have to click somewhere on the page or click the button directly to login.
[This is not preventing the click event to be captured, but the UI will display as disabled.]

Comment: Have you tried with a more specific condition? like `password !== ""` instead of `!password`

Comment: `Chrome autocomplete will fill in those value`: It fills password field too? If yes, then use `autocomplete="off"` html attribute for password field.

Comment: @Supamiu yes I tried but same. I think the issue is that ng2 added `disabled` attribute before autocomplete filled in but not changing this afterwards.

Comment: @AjeetShah autocomplete="off" does not seem to work in Chrome, there are plenty of threads talking about this. (actually it have this tag but auto filled in still)

Comment: I just ran into this exact issue myself. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @nhaesler programme a function and loops in ngAfterContentChecked, a bad practice...

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15917221/11322237

Answer (score 0):

Can you try readonly attribute in your input?

```html
[readonly] = "!password || !loginName"
```